# matlab index exceeds matrix dimensions with coordinates and date specification

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am trying to pull specific dates and coordinate locations out of a netcdf file and I am getting the error: 'index exceeds matrix dimensions'.

Here is my code:

```
strstart = datenum(1997, 05, 01);
strend = datenum(1998, 05, 30);
interval = datenum(1997,0,1,0,0,0) - datenum(1997, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
date_range = (strstart:interval:strend);
date_range1 = date_range';
boxedlon = lon1(86:121);
boxedlat = lat1(1:38);
ENSOPlot = nanmean(nanmean(wind(date_range1,boxedlat,boxedlon),2),1);
```

The line in question is here:

```
ENSOPlot = nanmean(nanmean(wind(date_range1,boxedlat,boxedlon),2),1);
```

I am very confused why as to why this error occurs because I have used this exact script on a previous netcdf file.

'wind' is a matrix with dimensions 365x73x144.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that `wind` is a standard Matlab function, and you didn't show what exactly it is. Nobody can understand what is the real error without all the elements. Please read [this guide on how to ask a good quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the number resulting from `strstart` and `strend` is way larger than the size of variable `wind`.

Could it be that you still need to subtract the date on which the `wind` data starts? Now you assume that the `wind` variable contains data from the past 2000 years...

Comment: It would look like that might be the case. My wind has dimensions of 365x73x144 while my date is 395x1. I will try what you suggest!